# Vehicle inventory program

Tags: python, python-3.x, homework

First time posting here, let me apologize ahead of time if this is not the correct format.. Anyway, I am new to programming and I am working on a school assignment to design a vehicle inventory system in Python (assignment details below). The code seems to be working as it should. I am questioning the 'update vehicle' function I defined outside of the class, whether it would make more sense to change to a class method. Or any other feedback anyone has. Thanks.
Create a final program that meets the requirements outlined below.

Assignment:
Create an automobile class that will be used by a dealership as a vehicle inventory program.  The following attributes should be present in your automobile class:

- private string make
- private string model
- private string color
- private int year
- private int mileage

Your program should have appropriate methods such as:

- constructor
- add a new vehicle
- remove a vehicle
- update vehicle attributes

At the end of your program, it should allow the user to output all vehicle inventory to a text file.

```
class Automobile:

    def __init__(self):
        self.make = " "
        self.model = " "
        self.color = " "
        self.year = 0
        self.mileage = 0


    def add_vehicle(self):
        self.year = int(input("Enter year: "))
        self.make = input("Enter make: ")
        self.model = input("Enter model: ")
        self.color = input("Enter color: ")
        self.mileage = int(input("Enter mileage: "))

    def __str__(self):
        return('%d %s %s Color: %s Mileage: %d' %
              (self.year, self.make, self.model, self. color,
               self.mileage))

vehicle_list = []

def edit(vehicle_list):
    pos = int(input('Enter the position of the vehicle to edit: '))
    new_vehicle = car.add_vehicle()
    new_vehicle = car.__str__()
    vehicle_list[pos-1] = new_vehicle
    print('Vehicle was updated')

user=True
while user:
    print ("""
    1.Add a Vehicle
    2.Delete a Vehicle
    3.View Inventory
    4.Update Inventory
    5.Export Inventory
    6.Quit
    """)
    ans=input("What would you like to do? ") 
    if ans=="1": 
        car = Automobile()
        car.add_vehicle()
        vehicle_list.append(car.__str__())

    elif ans=="2":
        for i in vehicle_list:
            vehicle_list.pop(int(input('Enter position of vehicle to remove: ')))
            print('Successfully removed vehicle')
    elif ans=="3":
        print(vehicle_list)
    elif ans=="4":
        edit(vehicle_list)
    elif ans=='5':
        f = open('vehicle_inv.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(vehicle_list))
        f.close()
    else:
        print('try again')
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get great answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The assignment mentions *private* fields. In Python those are created ([faked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064212/96588), really) by prefixing the field with two underscores, as in `__make`.
2. Interactive command line programs are a scourge, because they are a pain to automate (including for testing purposes). Have a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to create a non-interactive program which would be called for example as `./automobile.py add "My car"`. In general there are no `input` calls in 99.998% of production code.
3. I'm not sure whether this recommendation is Pythonic, but I prefer creating a pretty-print method rather than overriding `__str__` for printing the object in a user readable format.
4. The `edit` method takes a parameter which shadows an existing name. This is a common source of confusion and bugs.
5. `add_vehicle` should be inlined into `__init__`. It doesn't actually *add* a vehicle (which would mean adding it *to* something, such as `vehicle_list`), but rather initializes the vehicle fields, making it effectively a constructor.
6. Your code does not print the existing fields of a vehicle before replacing it. This may or may not be outside the scope of the assignment, but it is a usability issue.
7. The `user` variable serves no purpose and can be inlined.
8. `edit` asks for a one-offset index but when deleting a vehicle you use a zero-offset. You can use one or the other (ideally zero-offset for libraries and one-offset for user facing stuff) but it should be consistent.
9. Use `with open(...)` to guarantee closing the file cleanly.

Comment: Regarding 3: Overriding `__str__` is pythonic, but calling it directly is not (which is true for all magic methods). One can do `str(car)` instead.

Comment: Double underscores are for name mangling, not private attributes. 'Private' attributes, by convention, are prefixed with a *single* underscore.